# VsCode does show output of console.log in the Chrome

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, console.log

I have 2 projects. At one of them everything is fine. But at my 2nd project I cannot see the outputs of the console.log("STH")

This code works
alert("XXX")

But this is not
console.log("XXX")

I have also removed and re installed the VsCode but problem is still alive.
I use VsCode + Tsx. I was not able to solve the problem. And I can not do development now.
My extensions are:
Gitlens
prettier ESLint
Pretty Typescript Errors
SonarLint
Tailwind CSS Intellisense

launch.json is like this

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
I have a craco.config.js file like this

```js
        plugins: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: undefined,
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true,
                        drop_debugger: true,
                        pure_funcs: ['console.log']
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    /*  webpack: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
        }
    }, */
```

I removed drop_console and drop_debugger and and re-installed the redux-devtools extension ( which I believe this caused this issue) everything works fine right now.

Comment: how do vscode and

Comment: I also recloned the repo another place and this is the situation I am encountering

Comment: Maybe I have broke the debugger settings at Vscode @zapl